# Yahoo, OAuth http request. Works on localhost but not live server

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, yahoo

I have this code that is trying to authenticate with Yahoo! It works fine on my local sever but the same request made on my live server fails. It comes back with a (401) Unauthorized error when it calls `GetResponse()`. Can anyone help me understand why? Let me know if you need more information.

```
try
{
    string url = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_callback=" + Server.UrlEncode("http://www.dowdlefolkart.com/extensions/contacts/webform1.aspx");
    url = GetUrl(url, consumerKey, consumerSecret);

    var req = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    using (var res = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    {
        ....
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("ERROR" + ex.Message);
}
```

Here is the full Error Exception:

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 
at NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Web.Extensions.Contacts.WebForm1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
at ASP.extensions_contacts_webform1_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Update:

I am getting this error with Fiddler.

`oauth_problem=timestamp_refused&oauth_acceptable_timestamps=1314119105-1314120305`

So it looks like my timestamp from the live server is not correct. This is how I am creating the timestamp:

`string timestamp = Math.Floor((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds).ToString();`

Comment: Is your live server beind a proxy?

Comment: I am not sure. How can I check?

Comment: type `ping www.yahoo.com` from a command prompt from your live server or ask your network administrator.

Comment: Okay the result was: 
`Pinging any-fp3-real.wa1.b.yahoo.com [69.147.125.65] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 69.147.125.65: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=56
Reply from 69.147.125.65: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=56
Reply from 69.147.125.65: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=56
Reply from 69.147.125.65: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 69.147.125.65:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 7ms, Maximum = 9ms, Average = 8ms`

Comment: Right, so no proxy server. Could you POST the full exception stacktrace you are getting? Also it would help if you could trace the request. You could use Fiddler for this.

Comment: What am I exactly looking for when it traces the request?

Comment: you could compare it to the working version from your dev server and see how it differs.

Comment: I updated my question with some results from Fiddler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The reason for the error was due to an invalid timestamp. It was just slightly larger than that which was allowed. Using Fiddler i was able to determine this issue. The error was: `oauth_problem=timestamp_refused&oauth_acceptable_timestamps=1314119105-1314120305`.

I then logged onto my live server and adjusted the system clock to what it needed to be. Apparently it was 15 minutes fast. Once I adjusted this the error disappeared. Thank you @Darin Dimitrov for the assistance.

Comment: Is it really because of the timestamp? I am having a similar problem, but I am testing my app with local Java app on my desktop, where do I need to match the timestamp?